# Python create dictionary from ldif file

Tags: python, ldap, ldif

My_ldif loos like:

```
Dn: sample,dc=sample,dc=com Objectclass: top 
Objectclass: organizational 
Cn: sample 
Address: 123 
Address: 345 ..........................
```

And so on for multiple lines

I can get the output in dictionary with key and value but it only returns single key and value. As my `ldif` file has multiple `objectclass` and address values, how can I get multiple values assigned to a key in a dictionary?

Output should like as follows:

> `Myldif_dic = [ {‘dn’: ‘sample,dc=sample,dc=com’, ‘objectclass’: ‘top,organizational’ , ‘address’: ‘123’,’345’}]`

Can some help on this?